# Custom component declaration error in ionic2

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, angular2-components

```
@Input() map: google.maps.Map;
```

How can I declare these statement in various format because google contains invalid declaration.

Comment: do you mean `google` is throwing error? Also which maps library/ cordova plugin are you using? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Yes google as showing an error  install the plugin  npm install @typing/googlemap

Comment: Try with                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  @Input() map: any;                                                                                                          this.map= new google.maps.Map(...)